# How can I make a general makefile that selects all files with a specific extension

Tags: makefile

How does a makefile look like that makes a target for every extension?

My current makefile:

```
SOURCES=*.gnuplot   
TARGETS=$(SOURCES:.gnuplot=.pdf)

all: $(TARGETS)

%.pdf: %.gnuplot
        cp $< $@
```

The problem is that there is only 1 target: *.pdf and not test.pdf as I wanted.

How can I let this make file make a pdf file for every gnuplot file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.gnuplot)
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I can't believe how long it took me to find this. =P

Comment: Damn, I knew it but I always forget it. Thanks!